# How to install a specific version of nuget (2.12) on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, debian, .net-core, nuget

There is an open c#-project that needs `nuget 2.12` to get it compiled.
The problem is that the nuget package from the debian repositories only offer `2.8.7`.

There is the option to update nuget independently with `sudo nuget update -self` but it then installs 4.5.1 , which isn't compatible either.

Is there a way to install nuget 2.12 on Debian 9.4?

Comment: What kind of project requires such an old build? You probably should also dump that project, as it can be out-of-date. If you do need 2.12, today you can only build it from source yourself, https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/tree/2.12

Comment: Was there a breaking change that makes your project no longer work with more recent versions? NuGet should be backwards compatible

Answer (score 1):

first remove old nuget and mono installation

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mono-devel nuget
```

and try this:

https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin

then install nuget:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel nuget
```

Comment: This answer does not describe clearly what the intention is; You mean to specify a specific repo to pull the packages from and then re-install.